# JavaScript - Is it possible to add receiptients in Outlook appointment and send invitation to the attendees?

Tags: javascript, outlook

I have triyed the following code that is working fine, but it sends the reminder only to the Outlook of the computer that execute the script.

```
// create outlook object
var objOutlook = new ActiveXObject( "Outlook.Application" );
var olAppointmentItem = 1; //fixed for different properties of outlook object
var objAppointment = objOutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem);
objAppointment.ReminderSet = true;
objAppointment.Categories = 'Yellow Category';
objAppointment.Subject = subject;
objAppointment.Location = 'My Location';
objAppointment.RequiredAttendees = 'test@test.com';
objAppointment.Recipients.Add('test@test.com');

objAppointment.Start = appDate;
var duration = 2;
objAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60 * 24 * 7; 

objAppointment.Duration = duration; 
objAppointment.Save();
objAppointment.Send();
```

Comment: I am facing same problem. I cant sent Appointments for recipients. Have you fixed it?

Comment: your code wont send. You need to set meeting type. Than it will work

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working? If you want to send a meeting request, call `AppointmentItem.Send` after adding recipients.

Comment: I want also to invite the attendees of the appointment so as to receive the invitation

Comment: Every attendee added using Recipients.Add will receive the invitation.

Comment: Again is not able to send the invitation to the attendees... I have ammend the code! see my changes and let me know if youcan find my mistake.. My script is working and creating the meeting on the local aoutlook, but the problem is that cannot send the invitation to the attendees....

Comment: Does 'user@test.com' receive the invitation? What does the second half of your code do? Why would you want to retrieve the first item in the folder (which will be some random item in the Calendar folder)?

Comment: No the user@test.com do not receive the invitation... I have remove the second half ofmy code because I used it for some older testings...

Comment: Do you see an invitation in the Sent Items folder?

Comment: No I dont see any invitation in the send items folder. The only think that happens is to create the appointment in my own outlook. Then if you open the appointment screen of the outlook there is a button called 'Invide Attendees'. I have to press that button to invide the attendees. Does any way to do the invitation through the javascript without the need of the user to press that button?

Comment: What is your latest code? You call Send twice and continue to set properties after Send was called.

Comment: I have update the code of the question with my latest code!

Comment: Looks fine to me, but you are adding the same attendee twice.

Comment: I am facing same problem. I cant sent Appointments for recipients. Have you fixed it?